# Constraint problems when drop Not null on IBM iseries AS400

Tags: sql, constraints, ibm-midrange

Please help me with this, I execute

```
ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE DATA CAPTURE NONE;
ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE ALTER MY_COLUMN DROP NOT NULL;
```

but then I have the followed error:

> SQL State: 57007
>
> Vendor Code: -910
>
> Message: [SQL0910] The MY_TABLE object type * FILE MY_SCHEMA has a pending change.
>
> Cause . . . . . : The MY_TABLE object has a
> pending change made under commitment control is preventing this
> operation. You may have produced one of the following circumstances:
>
> - This application process has performed an operation on this object
>   under commitment control. The transaction is not committed. The
>   application process is now trying to change the same object using the
>   commitment control level of * NONE.
> - A different process application
>   has performed an operation on this object under commitment control.
>   The transaction is not committed.
> - This application process has
>   performed an operation on this object under commitment control using a
>   different definition of commitment. The transaction is not committed.
> - This application process has performed an operation on this object under commitment control. The transaction is not committed.
>
> You can not change the table until commit or roll back the changes.
>
> Retrieval. Do one of the following and retry the request:
>
> - If your application
>   process issued the uncommitted operation, run a COMMIT or ROLLBACK
>   before attempting any other operation on this object, or issue the
>   statement from a program using a commitment control level other than *
>   NONE.
> - If the application process that issued the uncommitted
>   operation on this object is not to your application, then that
>   application process must perform a COMMIT or ROLLBACK.
> - If the
>   application process issued the uncommitted operation using a different
>   definition of commitment, issue a COMMIT or ROLLBACK to the definition
>   of commitment.
> - Issue COMMIT or ROLLBACK before attempting an ALTER
>   TABLE statement on this subject.

Please help me!!

Comment: did you try COMMITing between alter tables?

Comment: I try to commit and rollback work after I get this mess, but it doesn't work. I can't delete the constraint from the iseries navigator or even set enabled to Yes, it stuck in Defined...

Comment: First   update my_column where my_column is null ....then alter the table.

Comment: Tagged "ibm-midrange", but what platform? The first `ALTER TABLE` statement is not (documented as) valid for DB2 for i, so what DB2 is used?

Comment: Well, I actually use it and now it is all blocked. It's DB" for i. I don't now how to realease the Change, or commit/rollback it. It appear in the journal but I don't now how to make the rollback.

Comment: `It appear in the journal...` **What** appears in the journal? What is the journal entry that appears?

Answer (score 1):

The condition indicates that prior work under commitment control was pending; either awaiting normal COMMIT or ROLLBACK, or that the prior processing was interrupted and the job has ended without being able to clean up the commit definition. There would have been prior messages logged in the joblog to inform more of the condition than what the sqlcode=-910 and the msg SQL0910 can reveal; the spooled joblog would have revealed, most likely the prior msg CPF325E with the activation group and logical unit of work, preceded by a msg CPF70A6 with a reason code. Without the spooled joblog, and reviewing for such previously logged messages, the origin is unlikely to be learned; however there is the option to use the Work With Commitment Def[initions] (WRKCMTDFN) [with the option to search all jobs], and as already mentioned, to review the journal for what transactions were requested but never committed.

If origin by an interrupted process that no longer exists, the IPL will run a journal/commit/database *recovery* phases in the SCPF joblog [for which that IPL-time job has the joblog spooled after the system-portion of the IPL completes; i.e. looking at the active SCPF joblog is of no help], and messaging logged to QSYSOPR and/or QHST [see DSPLOG QHST for both, in addition to the spooled QPJOBLOG from the SCPF job for the IPL after the issue].

If the problem were to persist after an IPL, then the Reclaim Storage (RCLSTG) for *ALL [optionally omitting anything else; though best not to omit *DBXREF for which a *lost* DB change may be manifest later as an error when re-creating or otherwise performing work on the database file for which there were prior errors/recovery activity -- though if omitted on the SELECT(*ALL) request, a second request could be to just RCLSTG SELECT(*DBXREF).

Note: There have been past defects whereby work *not performed* under commitment control has incorrectly left a file *in recovery* with an indication that prior work was done under commitment control; the effect is little different, than a different message identifier, such that in both cases the file pending work is protected from other change activity. Interrupted work outside of those running under isolation are permitted to be deleted, for example with Delete File (DLTF) or DROP TABLE -- errors logged during the request are ignored by the DB, but be careful to review the messaging for conditions indicating a possible issue pending being encountered, such as that the member was not deleted, which means that a replacement for the file irrespective of create, restore, or add member will fail. Such difficulties are likely to be resolved only by contacting a service provider.